# What happens to the British pound if the dollar collapses?

Tags: united-states

Hypothetically, if the dollar's value collapsed either over night or a fast down hill crash, what would happens to the value of the British pound?

Comment: what do you exactly mean by this? All currency values are relative to each other, in terms of other currencies nothing should happen (since you don't specify any event that would affect GBP) in terms of dollars it has to appreciate just because dollar value decreased

Comment: The US is hugely indebted to Britain!  There would be substantial defaults.

Comment: @1muflon1 I mean for example the Turkish lira recently lost 80% of its value against the dollar. Usually the dollar is used as a reference for other currencies values. But what if the dollar value itself drops? Does it drop against all currencies? I am only interested in what would happen to the British pound

Comment: @Mocas every currency can be used as a reference for every single currency all currency prices are relative to each others. USD is just quoted so much because US is the biggest world economy, there is nothing magical about it

Comment: What if a dollar was worth only 20 cents, which itself is only worth 4 cents

Comment: @1muflon1 ok, let's take the Chinese Yuan. If the dollar value against the Yuan drops by 95%, what would happen to the British pound value against the Yuan?

Comment: @GwendolynAnderson why would that happen? If you can explain with some references please submit an answer.

Comment: @Mocas it would automatically increase against yuan. Are you really confused by this? Any value of currency is by definition relative. There is no meaningful difference between saying that yuan value dropped and that value of all other currencies increased

Comment: @1muflon1 Hi, I don't think what you wrote is clearly true. At least I don't see why GBP would automatically become stronger relative RMB if RMB became stronger relative to USD. Perhaps you read the comment too hastily again.

Comment: @Giskard I was still under assumption that OP keeps the assumption in the question that general value of USD drops

Comment: Sure, but what does that imply that the answer to their question (emphasis by me) "*what would happen to the **British pound** value against the **Yuan**?*" is "*it would automatically increase against yuan*"?

Comment: @Giskard oh okay, I misread that as first currency being also GBP, yea if something happens to dollar and not to yuan then the relative value of yuan and GBP would be the same, but still what I have written holds, because there is no meaningful difference between saying that both yuan and GBP are now more valuable

Comment: @1muflon1 I find it fascinating that people on this forum refuse to clearly own their mistakes. I wonder if it is specific to economists/academics/young professionals? So you misread something, big whoop, it happens to everyone. There is no need to rationalize it, especially if the rationalization is obviously wrong.

Comment: @Giskard ? I am not trying to rationalize it. The argument that currencies are relative is robust to that error. Are you seriously claiming that currencies are not relative, since you claim it’s obviously wrong? Regarding the part that wasn’t robust to the error I corrected myself, if USD weakens (and nothing else happens it’s just one of shock to USD like OP says) then nothing should happen between relative value of yuan and GBP again I don’t see what’s obviously wrong about my correction to previous comment or how is it a rationalization

Comment: Didn't Greece have a problem when US had a big economic issue, 15 years ago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [If the dollar value against the Yuan drops by 95%, what would happen to the British pound value against the Yuan?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/57860/what-happens-to-the-british-pound-if-the-dollar-collapses#comment95957_57860)

The generalist answer to your question is the economist's go-to: "It depends."

It depends on the underlying reason for this giant drop in value. Why did the RMB/USD exchange rate drop 95%? Did China unveil incredible economic data that means its exports will be sought the world over? Did Russia nuke the US, decreasing the future value of its exports? Was it a computer glitch that will be corrected in a few minutes? These would all imply different reactions in the RMB/GBP exchange rate.

Comment: Pick the worst possible scenario...